# Genetic algorithm - shift planning

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I have some basic genetic algorithm knowledge, I've programmed a simple application finding X maximizing value of some function, but what I'm struggling with now is how should chromosome, individual, population etc. look like for some more complex problems like shift planning. Let's say we have some employees, some shifts and we want to assign them to each other. How shall the key parts of genetic algorithm look like to make it work for such data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me make a few assumptions to showcase an example of how you can make a genetic algorithm model for this problem.

### Assumptions

1. Let there be *n* employees labelled e_1, e_2, ..., e_n and n shifts labelled s_1, s_2, ..., s_n
2. Let n be an *even* number for simplicity of explanation

### Chromosome of an individual

Let each chromosome consist of *n* 2D tuples. Each tuple is a pair of a shift and an employee (s_i, e_i). *n* tuples is thus a mapping of all the employees to the shifts. Thus a chromosome will look something like this:

> { {s_x1, e_y1}, {s_x2, e_y2}, ... {s_xn, e_yn} }
>
> where, xi, yi c {1,2, ..,n} for all i, 
> s_xi != s_xj for i != j, 
> e_yi != e_yj for i != j

### Population

Depending on *n* we can have a population of *D* individuals each with the above chromosome configuration. You can start by randomizing the chromosome configurations for the *D* organisms at the start (although there can be better ways to do this).

### Reproduction

Given a generation of *D* individuals pick any two individuals, say d_i and d_j, for **crossover**. Let us obtain 2 children in the next generation, say c_i and c_j. It should look like this (considering *n* as 4 for simplicity):

> d_i = { {s_i1, e_i1}, {s_i2, e_i2}, s_i3, e_i3, {s_i4, e_i4} }
> d_j = { {s_j1, e_j1}, {s_j2, e_j2}, s_j3, e_j3, {s_j4, e_j4} }

crosses over to reproduce,

> c_i = { {s_i1, e_j3}, {s_i2, e_j2}, s_i3, e_j1, {s_i4, e_j4} }
> c_j = { {s_j1, e_i3}, {s_j2, e_i2}, s_j3, e_i1, {s_j4, e_i4} }

How you do this computationally for larger *n* is what I will let you think.

I also have some ideas on how one can apply *mutation* to the model, but I will let you think that through as well (moreover this is just an example model to get you started).

### Thoughts on a fitness function

Lets consider you have a cost fitness function called *employee satisfaction* which is a summation of *happiness* (say an integer between -10 and 10) of all employees within an individual of a population.

Now, say an employee (e_1) if given a certain shift (s_1), his happiness is -4, but if given another shift (s_4), his happiness is 10.

Then, the fitness (*employee satisfaction*) of an individual in the population can simply be (there can be more complicated mathematical functions for this) the sum of happiness of all *n* employees. The ideal best fitness scenario would be all employees have 10 *happiness* and *employee satisfaction* sums to *n x 10* compared to the worst fitness (least *employee satisfaction*) being *n x -10*.

Comment: thanks! Just wondering - what if I have shifts with different employee requirements - for example one shift requires one employee but other shift requires two employees? Shall my chromosome consist of 3D tuples instead of 2D then, containing null if only one employee is assigned?